# Labels with slanted rows in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

Trying to draw the following diagram via tikzcd, however I am not able to draw the small mapping arrows.

[image]

Please note that there is a missing first coordinate in the second mapping.

For reference, the original can be found on page 169 of https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-12492-5.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Text.Se! Please provide the code of what you have tried so far. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to add rows and make the mapping arrows come from new cells. It requires a bit of tweaking to get the spacing right.

Also, it looks like there's a typo in the map from the third entry of the first row: I added the missing coordinate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=5mm, row sep=2mm]
\arrow[r]&L^{-i}\arrow[r]&
    Y\oplus L^{-i}\oplus L^{-i+1}\arrow[r]\arrow[ddddl,end anchor={[xshift=-1mm]}]&
    Y\oplus L^{-i+1}\oplus L^{-i+2}\arrow[r]\arrow[ddddl,start anchor={[xshift=-7mm]}]& 
    L^{-i+2}\oplus L^{-i+3}\arrow[r]\arrow[ddddl,start anchor={[xshift=-7mm]}]& 
    L^{-i+3}\oplus L^{-i+4}\arrow[r]\arrow[ddddl,start anchor={[xshift=-7mm]}]&\cdots\\
&&(y,l,l')\arrow[mapsto,ddl,start anchor={[xshift=2mm]},end anchor={[shift={(13mm,2mm)}]}]&
    (y,l,l')\hspace{16.5mm}\arrow[mapsto,ddl,start anchor={[xshift=-2.5mm]},end anchor={[shift={(16mm,2mm)}]}]&
    (l,l')\hspace{16mm}\arrow[mapsto,ddl,start anchor={[xshift=-2.5mm]},end anchor={[shift={(15.5mm,2mm)}]}]&
    (l,l')\hspace{15mm}\arrow[mapsto,ddl,start anchor={[xshift=-2.5mm]},end anchor={[shift={(13.5mm,2mm)}]}]\\
\\
&\lefteqn{\hspace{11mm}\hspace{1mm}l}&
    \lefteqn{\hspace{12mm}(y,0,l)}&
    \lefteqn{\hspace{11mm}(0,0,l)}&
    \lefteqn{\hspace{10mm}(0,l)}\\
\arrow[r]&L^{-i}\arrow[r]&
    Y\oplus L^{-i}\oplus L^{-i+1}\arrow[r]& 
    Y\oplus L^{-i+1}\oplus L^{-i+2}\arrow[r]& 
    L^{-i+2}\oplus L^{-i+3}\arrow[r]&
    \lefteqn{\cdots}\phantom{ L^{-i+3}\oplus L^{-i+4}}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I added the missing coordinate and in the process also added back the Y in the third entry in both the first and second row. As the widths were now different, I tweaked a bit with xshift and came up with this code: https://pastebin.com/yhJxiLQG. However, the spacing in my version is far from ideal.

Comment: @RobertoReale: I edited my response and cleaned up the spacing.

Comment: Thank you for the editing!